# Cl 6 vs Cl 9 In a Poweredge r710

Tags: performance, dell, memory

I have a Dell Poweredge R710.  Right now it has 12 2GB, Cl=6 (per SIW),  dual ranked, PC3-8500 RDIMMs running in Advanced ECC mode.  I'd like to add 24 additional GBs.

I found this:

http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=554271D7A5CA7304

(Dual Ranked, 4GB,  RDIMM, PC3-10600, CL=9).  I was thinking about getting 6 of these 4GB RDIMMS. My question:

**Will adding the CL=9 RDIMMs cause a significant performance hit?**

The server is running Server 2008 R2. It's primary purpose is to host a bunch (~5) of Hyper-V VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mix RAM your system will operate at the slowest speed of the RAM you have installed.

This link should be useful to you: http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-pedge-installing-upgrading-memory-11g.pdf

Comment: I'm talking about timings not speed.  I've ready the manual, but my question isn't answered.  What I want to know is if a difference in timings like that one described is enough to cause a real world noticeable difference?

Comment: After reading into this a bit more I found that you are going to have to switch your type from "Advanced ECC mode" to "otpimized" mode in order to use the third memory channel properly. See this document: http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/server-poweredge-11g-white-paper.pdf

Comment: As for timing you likely will not feel the difference. The size increase will be the big win in this case if you are good with the change described above.

Comment: Thanks!  With memory I'm never sure what the relative importance of the factors is (i.e i can can compare specs and say "hm 6 is lower than 9, I guess that's better" but I don't have a real sense of how significant that better was is.  In this case it sounds like more memory far outweighs performance hit from higher latency.  Thanks again!